# OncePerRequestFilter I can not return HttpServletResponse custom error

Tags: spring, httpresponse

I have OncePerRequestFilter:

```
public class ApiAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
...
@Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    String token = request.getHeader("X-Authorization");
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(token)) {
      //return custom exception
      return;
    }

    User user = userService.findUserByToken(token);
    if (user == null) {
      //return custom exception
      return;
    }

    AuthUser authUser = new AuthUser(token, user);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authUser);

    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
```

How can I return to client my custom exception?

I tried `response.sendError(777, "Authorization token is invalid");`

but client received error with status 500. I can send onli CONSTANT errors from `HttpServletResponse` loke this:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_PROXY_AUTHENTICATION_REQUIRED, "Authorization token required");
```

But this `HttpServletResponse` not have all codes. For example I want send 666 error.

Comment: You can extend the standard HttpServletResponse class and make your own constants.